# ERROR 3011 ACCESS 2007

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Hey everyone ive been checking on this site for some similar issues but i haven't found a response to my problem. My line that keeps crashing is:

```
  DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "MY_FUT_REPORT", "U:\Desktop\TEST.xls", True, "FUTURE"
```

So MY_FUT_REPORT is a report and i want to transfer it into and excel sheet. I then have the following line below i want to append to the existing sheet.

```
    DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "MY_ND_REPORT", "U:\Desktop\TEST.xls", True, "NEXT DAY"
```

So far the first line crashes i've create multiple files to the same path and it works, also ive tried this line

DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputReport, "MY_FUT_REPORT", acFormatXLS, "U:\Desktop\TEST.xls", 0

which works perfectly so i am wondering what the issue is ive also tried the commands by replacing it to acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, but still no success. Can anyone help me!!!!

Comment: ive been doing more research i think i can't export a report like this

Answer (score 0):

You hinted at your answer in a comment. Anyway, you are correct you cannot export a report using [DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff844793.aspx). In order to get the results you expect, you will need to change the part in your code where you call out the report name, to the actual underlying data for the report I.E. the report's Record Source.

Comment: The only reason i would have liked the report to be the data source and not its underlying query, is because of the format it come out when exported in excel.